# searching the result from mysql should be display in one alertbox

Tags: javascript, php

In the below code i have a php code when i search for a particular variable ie iam looking for a variable which starts in b.All the variable which starts in b are displaying one by one in alertbox.But i want to display in one alert.
Actual result:it displays one by one alert

```
<?php  
$search = (isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : null);

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db ("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `coursemaster` WHERE `course_code` LIKE '%$search%' or `course_name` like '%$search%'";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

  if($result) 
   {    
      while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))   
       {      
          echo"<script>alert('ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]');</script>";  
       }    
     }
   else
     { 
       echo "No result";  
     }
 ?>

<form action="coursemaster_view" method="post">  
 <center> SEARCH:<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH"><br></center>  
 <center> <input type="submit" class="btn-success btn"></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the result in one variable and then echo at last. Check out the below code.

```
      $msg='';
     if($result) 
     {    
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))   
       {      
            $msg=$msg ."ID=".$row[0].",COURSE CODE=".$row[1].",COURSE NAME=".$row[2];
           //echo"<script>alert('ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]');</script>";  
       }   
        echo"<script>alert('$msg');</script>";  
     }
   else
     { 
       echo "No result";  
     }
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Comment: remove = and put : try that.

Comment: do not put = or : just try without these. See what you get?

Comment: it is working good but without searching and execute the code it is displaying alertbox.

Comment: it is working but without searching the data it is displaying the alertbox @Gourav

Comment: @MosesVickson : Try and find out, there may be some silly mistake.Anyways if you find my answer was helpful can vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("';

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))   
{      
    echo "ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]";  
}
echo '")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: before searching alert box is displaying @RiggsFolly

Comment: @MosesVickson That is what would have happened before this code change. You need to give the submit button a ` name="something"` attribute and then test that the button was actually pressed before execution of any of this PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP to build a string and echo that string.

```
$message = "";
if($result){    
  while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){      
    $message.="ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]";
  }    
  echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
}else{ 
  echo "No result";  
}
```

Also you shouldn't use alert. For example if this returned 1000 results you would be really annoyed. Use console.log.

Comment: i got this error  SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in C:\wamp\www\look.php on line 10 @DutGRIFF

Comment: @MosesVickson Sorry. I had a var before my variable declaration. I was mixing my languages. I need a way to quickly test me PHP like I do with client side.

Comment: When i execute the code without searching i got  ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]ID=$row[0],COURSE CODE=$row[1],COURSE NAME=$row[2]

Comment: @MosesVickson Looks like really needed to test my original code. How is this?

Comment: i got this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\look.php on line 17
@DutGRIFF

Comment: @MosesVickson I missed a semi-colon. Ha. This is just getting better and better.